# Python new_list = list(old_list) does not clone the list

Tags: python

I searched and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) from a guy asking how to clone a list in Python since just doing `new_list = old_list` simply copied the reference.

The thread says that `new_list = list(old_list)` works, but I have tried it out and when I edit `new_list`, `old_list` also changes.

Did something change or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Same behavior, doesn't copy the list

Comment: What's in the list? Is it other references? Your code won't make a deep copy.

Comment: The list has other lists inside. So it's doing a shallow copy. Is there a way to do this without including "copy" to deepcopy it?

Comment: So everything in python is an object. while `new_list = list(old_list)` creates a new list, the references to the objects of in old list is unchanged. When you modify the objects pointed by the references they will still change.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you

Comment: The thread you cited includes the caveat that, if your original list contains references to other objects, then you need a `deepcopy`.  That appears to be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try copy.deepcopy

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> b[1]
2
>>> b[0] = 'a'
>>> b
['a', 2, 3]
>>> a
['a', 2, 3]
>>> import copy
>>> c = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> c[0] = 'pink'
>>> c
['pink', 2, 3]
>>> a
['a', 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid importing things but if it's necessary I guess I'll use it

Answer (score 0):

What it does copy is the *references* contained within the list, but not the objects those references point to.

Consider:

```
>>> l1 = [{}, {}]
>>> l2 = list(l1)
```

Now if I add another element to `l1` it does not magically appear in `l2`:

```
>>> l1.append({})
>>> l1
[{}, {}, {}]
>>> l2
[{}, {}]
```

However, if I modify the contents of one of the object in `l1`, the corresponding object in `l2` also changes:

```
>>> l1[0]['key1'] = 'value1'
>>> l1
[{'key1': 'value1'}, {}, {}]
>>> l2
[{'key1': 'value1'}, {}]
```

What you want is [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: Yes I see it's happening because I'm using lists inside lists

Answer (score 0):

Observe the following:

```
old_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

new_list = old_list

old_list[3] = 10
```

Yields:

```
[1, 2, 3, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 10]
```

Instead, you can do the following:

```
old_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

new_list = old_list[:]

old_list[3] = 5
```

Yields:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
new_list = copy.deepcopy(old_list)
```